# PHP variable lost after inspection in XDebug

Tags: php, drupal, phpstorm, xdebug

I am unsure if this is expected behaviour as I am relatively new to the environment but every time I inspect a variable in the IDEA console the 2nd time I inspect it seems to have been set to null.

```
 $node->field_price
 [7]

 $node->field_price
 NULL
```

Setup: Intellij IDEA, Xdebug, DrupalVM, Drupal 8, PHP 5.3

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck asking the Jetbrains tech support.

Comment: Thanks i will ask them now.